# A PHP Error Message: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i'm a newbie in codeigniter , just i got this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: views/coba.php
Line Number: 52
```

and still i can't solve it. this my code on controller:

```
public function getvalue()
{
 $result = $this->admin_model->harga();
 $data = array(
        'harga' => $result,
    );
 if ($this->input->post('btnKirim')==true) {
  $data['nama']=$this->input->post('nama');
  $data['tgl_masuk']=$this->input->post('tgl_masuk');
  $data['tgl_ambil']=$this->input->post('tgl_ambil');
  $data['berat']=$this->input->post('berat');
  $data['status']=$this->input->post('status');

 }
 $data['judul'] = 'Halaman Pegawai';
 $data['content'] = 'coba';
 $this->load->view('template/index',$data);

}
```

and this code for my model :

```
public function harga(){
    $query= $this->db->query('SELECT harga from satuan');
    return $query->result();
}
```

it's my view.php on where i got this error message:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="total" class="control-label">Total Harga</label>
<div>
    <input name="total" id="total" type="numeric" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $harga; ?>" readonly='total'>
</div>
</div>
```

Why am I getting this message, what can I do to solve it?

Comment: It's means that `$this->admin_model->harga()` returns an array, but your code expects it to be a string. Check your model's method to see why this happens.

Comment: Try `print_r($result);` and see what is returned

Comment: my model just select the query from database, but i don't know where it's getting wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method `result` either returns an array of objects or an empty array. Either way, method `harga` returns an array.

Since you're using that result to populate value of a field, it's not clear if you really want all results from a table or just some specific, maybe even just one result. Whatever you want, you need to convert that to a scalar value to be able to use `echo` without warnings.

It's possible to iterate over returned results, so you could do something like this:

```
public function harga() {

    // Since your HTML containts 'Total harga', I'm assuming you
    // have multiple results and you need to add them all up
    $result = 0

    foreach($query->result() as $row) {
        $output += $row->harga;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

If you need only one result, consider using `$query->row()` to get a single row from the table (and even better, use `limit` or `where` in your sql query).

To fully understand what your problem is, check the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can try code :

```
$result = $this->admin_model->harga();
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    $data['harga']= $row->harga;
}
```